# Check Dictionary.Add() key uniqueness at compile time

Tags: c#

Is there a way to check at compile time a dictionary's key uniqueness in a method scope when you add them with the `Add()` method?

Example: there are a bunch of payment solution providers (PayPal, PayEx, etc.) that give some sort of a status result when you query a transaction, lets say an integer. Since every PSP handles statuses differently, we have a fixed amount of system statuses (such as Pending, Aborted, Committed, etc.) that are mapped to the various status codes for each PSP.

```
public static class ResponseMapping
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<int, PaymentResult> ResultMap;

    static ResponseMapping()
    {
        ResultMap = new Dictionary<int, PaymentResult>();

        ResultMap.Add(1, PaymentResult.LogonError);
        ResultMap.Add(2, PaymentResult.Pending);
        ResultMap.Add(9, PaymentResult.Ok);

        // OH DEAR, THIS WILL BLOW UP
        ResultMap.Add(1, PaymentResult.Something);
    }

    public static PaymentResult FindAppropriateResponse(int resultCode)
    {
        if (ResultMap.ContainsKey(resultCode))
        {
            return ResultMap[resultCode];
        }

        return PaymentResult.UnknownResult;
    }
}
```

An easy shortcut would be to use the `[]` indexing notation to add each map, but with `Add()` you can avoid possibly overriding something that you didn't mean to.

Unfortunately, this way it blows up at runtime. Is there a technique that would make it blow up at compile time?

Comment: Unfortunately not, you could use some kind of compile-time code analysis in this simple case. The problem is while this might be feasible with a simple int, if your key is a complex class that implements GetHashCode and IEquatable, the compiler can't easily figure out duplicate keys.

Comment: I checked the collection initializer syntax and that still gives you a runtime error. I think the best you can do is a unit test.

Comment: As @Sign says the answer is a Unit Test and if you set it up to run during a build then that's as close to compile time as you can get.

Comment: I would use an "AddOrUpdate" extension method.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can check for key existence at compile time. Instead you can use [`Dictionary.ContainsKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx)  method  like:

```
int key = 1; //your key
if(!ResultMap.ContainsKey(key))
{
    ResultMap.Add(key, PaymentResult.Something);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ContainsKey`:

```
if(!ResultMap.ContainsKey(1))
{
    ResultMap.Add(1, PaymentResult.Something);
}
```

or `TryGetValue`:

```
obj item;
if(!ResultMap.TryGetValue(1, out item))
    ResultMap.Add(1, PaymentResult.Something);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really really need a dictionary object I don't think you can do it at compile time and can sort of fake it with a unit test. But if you just want a look up, use a switch.

```
public static PaymentResult FindAppropriateResponse(int resultCode)
{
    switch(resultCode)
    {
         case 1:
            return PaymentResult.LogonError;
         case 2:
            return PaymentResult.Pending;
         case 3:
             return PaymentResult.Ok;
         default:
             return PaymentResult.UnknownResult;
         case 1: // Does blow up at compile time
             return PaymentResult.Something;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a method which you use instead of Add.
It will add the value if not exists or replace it if it exists.

```
private void Add(Dictionary<int, PaymentResult> PaymentResults, int index, PaymentResult pResult)
{
    if(PaymentResults.ContainsKey(index))
    {
        PaymentResults[index] = pResult;
    }
    else
    {
        PaymentResults.Add(index, pResult);
    }
}
```

And to use it

```
this.Add(ResultMap, 1, PaymentResult.LogonError);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related but not exactly. I had the problem of I wasn't sure if a key would exist or not, so I created a simple method.

```
    private void AddKey(string key, string value)
    {
        if (!Dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
               Dictionary.Add(key, value);
    }
```

The just call AddKey(key,value);

Maybe this will help you some.

Comment: I don't think OP wants to override the value, like you're doing here.

Comment: this was more of a point in the right direction for the OP, he can edit it however he likes.

Answer (score 0):

Or extend

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool Push<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                dictionary[key] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                dictionary.Add(key, value);
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static TValue Pull<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
    {
        try
        {
            return dictionary.ContainsKey(key) ? dictionary[key] : default(TValue);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return default(TValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
    ResultMap = new Dictionary<int, PaymentResult>();

    ResultMap.Push(1, PaymentResult.LogonError); //1 -> PaymentResult.LogonError
    ResultMap.Push(1, PaymentResult.Something); //1 -> PaymentResult.Something
```